# keyboard interrupt lags in python pyserial module

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, keyboardinterrupt

I'm working in a proyect in Python that needs to read information through serial communication between a certain device and a PC and finish when ctrl+C or the stop script button is pressed, but it doesn't do that! It keeps waiting for data and terminates when the device sends serial information. What am I missing here? Is there a turnaround for this?

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6',baudrate=9600,timeout=None)
print("Start")
try:
    while True:
        text = ser.read_until()
        print(text)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Forced Finish")
ser.close()
```

I'm currently running this script in Spyder v3.3.1. My Python version is 3.6